# Get the list of files in "My Drive" using Google Drive API after Jun 1, 2020?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I know Google Drive API will enforce an update in the Mid of 2020.  However, I am very confused about the Drive API document, as described in [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and [Changes.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list) :

***supportsAllDrives*** :    Deprecated - Whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives. This parameter will only be effective until June 1, 2020. Afterwards all applications are assumed to support shared drives. (Default: false)

***includeItemsFromAllDrives***: Deprecated - Whether both My Drive and shared drive items should be included in results. This parameter will only be effective until June 1, 2020. Afterwards shared drive items will be included in the results. (Default: false)

My questions are:

1. Does this mean the **supportsAllDrives** & **includeItemsFromAllDrives** will automatically become **true** after Jun 1,2020, if these two parameters are not included (or are set to false) in the API requests?
2. Before Jun 1, 2020, we can easily retrieve files only in "My Drive" (without files in shared drives) by setting **supportsAllDrives** & **includeItemsFromAllDrives** to false.  But after Jun 1, 2020, how can I retrieve files only in "My Drive"??  I know we can filter the result returned by the Files.list requests to get rid of the files in shared drives, but it is very inefficient.  There should be a direct method to get the file list in "My Drive" only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 - **supportAllDrives** & **includeItemsFromAllDrives** will become true by default.

2 - Since there is no direct method to retrieve your own files, you have to use the **[q](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)** parameter on the **[Drive : list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)**.

You have two options:

> `'root' in parents` This will get you the files and folders you have on your **My Drive** excluding the shared ones, but it will not show files inside folders, just the ones in the front page of **My Drive**.

Best approach:

> `'me' in owners` This will get you all the files you own. This is the best option since you can't enforce an owner to a shared drive item.

If you try to enforce yourself as an owner of a shared drive item, this is what you will get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "ownerOnTeamDriveItemNotSupported",
    "message": "Owner role is invalid for shared drive items."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Owner role is invalid for shared drive items."
 }
}
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shared-drives-diffs):

> `owners`, `ownerNames`, `ownedByMe` — Files within a shared drive are owned by the shared drive, not individual users.

A part from that i recommend you to also use `trashed = false` in the **q** parameter, to be sure no trashed files appear on your search.

If you want to file this as a feature request you can go to [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106)

Comment: Thanks, @Kessy.   Setting up the Corpora to "drive" results in other limitations.  Still looking for an answer from the Google Drive API team.

Comment: I have just updated the ansewer. I hope you find it usefull.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  But I still wonder if there is an easier way to retrieve list/changes in "My Drive"

Comment: Is there a way to get the shared with me files and folders but only when listing the root folder?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the deprecations have been revoked. At least I can no longer find these Google Drive API notes in the API description and the parameters "includeItemsFromAllDrives" and "supportsAllDrives" are still present.

Comment: Yes, the old code still works well after Jun 1, 2020